# Why is my global requirejs var undefined?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, edx

I have two seperate applications. Both use jQuery an RequireJS. I want to embed application A into application B, so I transfer the required HTML to application B. Application B is an instance of edx-platform (https://github.com/edx/edx-platform).

So far so good, but the second app won't load. First I had both script tags with data-main, but it doesn't work. So I searched and I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10839885

I looks good so far, but my global requirejs variable is undefined. In the HTML edx-platform calls RequireJS with this code:

```
<script>
    window.baseUrl = "/static/";
    (function (require) {
        require.config({
            baseUrl: window.baseUrl
        });
    }).call(this, require || RequireJS.require);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/lms/js/require-config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (require) {
        require.config({
            paths: {
                'js/courseware/courseware_factory': 'js/courseware/courseware_factory',
                'draggabilly': 'js/vendor/draggabilly',
                'js/courseware/toggle_element_visibility': 'js/courseware/toggle_element_visibility',
                'js/courseware/course_home_events': 'js/courseware/course_home_events',
                'js/courseware/link_clicked_events': 'js/courseware/link_clicked_events',
                'moment': 'common/js/vendor/moment-with-locales',
                'moment-timezone': 'common/js/vendor/moment-timezone-with-data',
                'js/student_account/logistration_factory': 'js/student_account/logistration_factory',
                'js/groups/views/cohorts_dashboard_factory': 'js/groups/views/cohorts_dashboard_factory',
                'js/dateutil_factory': 'js/dateutil_factory',
                'js/courseware/accordion_events': 'js/courseware/accordion_events',
                'js/bookmarks/views/bookmark_button': 'js/bookmarks/views/bookmark_button',
                'js/views/message_banner': 'js/views/message_banner',
                'js/student_profile/views/learner_profile_factory': 'js/student_profile/views/learner_profile_factory'
            }
        });
    }).call(this, require || RequireJS.require);
</script>
```

My code is included later. I tried to run a simple `console.log(requirejs)` but it didn't work. requirejs is also undefined when calling it from the developer console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found out why it is undefined. edX also loads the file  which undefined all of those variables.

Now I need to find a way to get my code running.